# How to find texts and replace them using RegEx

Tags: regex, grep, wildcard, textwrangler

Below is an extract from my long text:

```
As a young researcher, he is required:
\n ÷ to read at least three theses\n ÷ to meet his tutor or supervisor 
once a week\n ÷ to join seminars\n
```

Now I would like to find any blocks starting with `÷` and ending with `\n`, and replace `÷` by `÷<font color="blue">` and `\n` by `</font>\n`. So, for example, my above extract would appear like this:

```
As a young researcher, he is required:
\n ÷<font color="blue"> to read at least three theses</font>\n ÷<font color="blue"> 
to meet his tutor or supervisor once a week</font>\n ÷<font color="blue"> to join seminars</font>\n
```

So far I have been using these Grep in TextWrangler to look for and replace:

```
(÷[^ \t/<>]*?).*?([^ \t/<>]*?\\n)

<font color="blue">\1\2</font>\3
```

The required blocks of text are successfully found, but replacing doesn't work as I expect.

I'm using TextWrangler, but may have access to BBEdit or Notepad++.

Can you please help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to DesertEagle, I have worked out the solution. Here is the code:

```
÷([^\\n]+)\\n
÷<font color="blue">\1</font>\\n
```

Comment: How does the replacing work? Can you post the results of that search and replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I don't have textwrangler at hand, this should work for you [1]

*search*
`/÷([^\n]+)\n/`

**EDIT**
The correct syntax for textwrangler is
`÷([^\\n]+)\\n`

*replace*
`÷<font color="blue">\1</font>\n`

[1] please ensure proper escaping for your engine

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this does not find.

Comment: try replacing the `+` with `*`

Comment: as i said, i do not have access to textwrangler, but i just saw a bad habbit of mine: remove the regex delimiters (`/.../`).

Comment: You have saved me a day. Thank you very much. A little change to your code does the trick. Please see my UPDATE.